# Show an empty result on succeeding rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table in MySQL

```
+----+------------+-----------+-------------+-------------------+
| id | product_id |  status   | transaction |      action       |
+----+------------+-----------+-------------+-------------------+
|  1 |          2 | Pending   |             | sent              |
|  2 |          2 | Complete  |           1 | received          |
|  2 |          2 | Complete  |           1 | some other action |
+----+------------+-----------+-------------+-------------------+
```

I want to show transaction only once after the Complete status.
so the result set would be

```
+----+------------+-----------+-------------+-------------------+
| id | product_id |  status   | transaction |      action       |
+----+------------+-----------+-------------+-------------------+
|  1 |          2 | Pending   |             | sent              |
|  2 |          2 | Complete  |           1 | received          |
|  2 |          2 | Complete  |             | some other action |
+----+------------+-----------+-------------+-------------------+
```

Comment: you want update statment ?

Comment: Does the result set need to be in that *exact* format?  What about using a query like: `SELECT id,product_id,Status,transaction,COUNT(*) as rows FROM myTable GROUP BY Status DESC` (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/31c9c/3)?

Comment: Thanks @RocketHazmat I need the information for the next complete status because it has a different create_time.. I was wondering if there was a way to only show the transaction of a complete status once and null on every row after that

Comment: @SamD: There might be, but it sounds a little over-complicated for an SQL query (you might be able to save the status of the previous row in an SQL variable).  How are you using the data, maybe you can ignore it for each new status in that language?

Comment: @RocketHazmat I have been trying to implement it in application level but the problem is this query is only a section of a lot of logic. I simplified the query but essentially it should be a group_concat listing all the transactions only once status hits complete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this in MySQL is using variables.  The query looks something like this:

```
select id, product_id, status,
       if(id <> @previd and @prevstatus <> status and status = 'Complete', transaction, NULL) as transaction,
       action,
       @previd := id, @prevstatus := status
from table t cross join
     (select @previd := -1, @prevstatus := '') const
order by id, product_id, status;
```

One problem is that the table doesn't have a column for a stable sort, so this is a best-guess.

Answer (score 1):

i dont know why are you inserting same result twice , this is bad practise.

try that

```
     SELECT  
         id, product_id , status, transaction from Table1
     group by id ,product_id,status
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3102b/1

Comment: this is an example my data is unique. Thanks.. this query wouldn't work for my case because i need the leading rows after complete I just don't want to show any transaction